# The polynomial $aX^2+bX+c$ of degree $2$ in a field $K$ with char$(K)\neq 2$ is irreducible if and only if $b^2-4ac$ is not a square in $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have to prove the following:

The polynomial $aX^2+bX+c$ of degree $2$ in a field $K$ with char$(K)\neq 2$ is irreducible if and only if $b^2-4ac$ is not a square in $K$.

I have never worked with irreducible polynomials before, so any hint or tip would be a great help!

Thank you!

Comment: A quadratic is irreducible iff it has no roots in your field.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial